# Loop using two related arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

When a button is clicked i want the results in the array to be listed for example: John Smith 16, Jack Snow 10 etc..

I want to use a loop however the code in my loop is incorrect at the moment as when i click the button all i get is: [object Object].

Can someone provide a possible fix?

```
 function begin() {
      listresults();
      ();
    }
    var results1 = {name:"John Smith", score:16};
    var results2 = {name:"Jack Sow", score:10};
    var results3 = {name:"Tessa Flip", score:15};
    var results = [results1, results2, results3];

    function listresults() {
      var text = "";
      var total = 0;
      var i;
    for (i in results) {
      text += results[i] + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = text;


    }
```

Comment: thats because you are appending objects instead of their values
try : `text += results[i].name + " " + results[i].score + "<br>";`

Comment: apending object  try this  text += results[i].name + ' '  results[i].score + "<br>";

Comment: Check my single line answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation

Answer (score 1):

I would first check that the lengths of the 2 arrays are the same. Then iterate using a for loop:

```
final int timeLength = TIME.length;
if (timeLength != stat.size()) {
    //something may not be right
}
for (int i = 0; i < timeLength; i++) {
    System.out.println(time[i]+" "+stat.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are appending objects instead of object values in the filed.

This is the proper way of accessing name and score from object which is returned when you are looping through your array of objects :

```
 function begin() {
      listresults();
      ();
    }
    var results1 = {name:"John Smith", score:16};
    var results2 = {name:"Jack Sow", score:10};
    var results3 = {name:"Tessa Flip", score:15};
    var results = [results1, results2, results3];

    function listresults() {
      var text = "";
      var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
      text += results[i].name + " " + results[i].score + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = text;
    }
```

Here is an [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/f982Lny4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use `Array` methods(map, join) instead of pure loops

```js
function begin() {
      listresults();
    }
    
    var results1 = {name:"John Smith", score:16};
    var results2 = {name:"Jack Sow", score:10};
    var results3 = {name:"Tessa Flip", score:15};
    var results = [results1, results2, results3];
    
    function listresults() {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 
         results.map(function(item) { 
           return item.name + ' ' + item.score; 
         }).join('<br>');
         
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 
         results.map(function(item) { 
           return item.score;
         }).reduce(function(sum, score) { 
           return sum + score;
         }, 0);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="begin()">begin</button>
<br />
<div id="message"></div>
<div>total: <span id="total">0</span></div>
```

Comment: thanks! One more question, how would i be able to total all of the scores? for example, 41 would be the total in this instance.

Comment: in  your for loop just do total += results[i].score; and after for loop console.log it or use it

Comment: @J.Doe added total score in example above

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing objects `results1, results2,` etc in the array `'results'`.
So while iterating the array you should access the object properties as shown below:

```
function listresults() {
      var text = "";
      var total = 0;
      var i;
    for (i in results) {
      text += results[i]['name'] + ' ' + results[i]['score'] + "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) and [**Array.join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example)

```js
var results1 = {name:"John Smith", score:16};
var results2 = {name:"Jack Sow", score:10};
var results3 = {name:"Tessa Flip", score:15};
var results = [results1, results2, results3];  

var res = results.map(item => { return item.name+ " " +item.score });

console.log(res.join(", "));
```